# Django model choice Text to Integer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I'm trying to create a django model using Text as a value for the IntegerField

```
class User(models.Model):

    class UserRole(models.IntegerChoices):
        FULLACCESS = 0, _('full_access_user')
        READONLY = 1, _('read_only_user')
        WRITEONLY = 2, _('write_only_user')

    role = models.IntegerField(choices=UserRole.choices)
```

When I try to create the user like
`User.objects.create(role="full_access_user")` it does not map the string value to integer.
Tried to define `models.IntegerChoices` as `models.TextChoices` and map those to integer but django forbids such action. What could be done to create the object like it's shown in the example ?

Comment: use `CharField(choices=......)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need a sane way of accessing these values, the standard way of doing this is by defining *constants* in your class:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ROLE_FULL_ACCESS = 0
    ROLE_READ_ONLY = 1
    ROLE_WRITE_ONLY = 2
    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        (ROLE_FULL_ACCESS, 'Full Access'),
        (ROLE_READ_ONLY, 'Read Only'),
        (ROLE_WRITE_ONLY, 'Write Only'),
    ]

    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
```

Usage:

```
User.objects.create(role=User.ROLE_FULL_ACCESS)
```

You could refactor this further but unless you'll actually reuse the resulting code somewhere else, it's usually unnecessary as the above would be able to cover ~99% of what you need to do.

Comment: yeah, after having some years on hand experience with django I can confirm this is the sane way of handling the case:) thanks for your answer