# Get the integer value of IntegerChoices given a string in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have

```
class AType(models.IntegerChoices):
    ZERO = 0, 'Zero'
    ONE = 1, 'One'
    TWO = 2, 'Two'
```

in Django 3.2.

Then `AType.choices` can be used as a dict, e.g. `AType.choices[0]` or `AType.choices[AType.ZERO]` is 'Zero'.

What's the easiest way to map from the string to the int (0, 1, 2), e.g., map 'Zero' to 0?

I could make another dict by iterating over each key, value pair, and use the other dict.  However, I wonder if there's a more convenient way.

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69667983/get-the-value-of-an-integerchoices-value-in-django) (other way), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056286/django-model-choice-text-to-integer) (doesn't have the answer), or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63453124/converting-string-to-integerchoice-value) (also doesn't have the answer).

**EDIT**: Here is my current solution, which is just hand-coded.

```
    @classmethod
    def string_to_int(cls, the_string):
        """Convert the string value to an int value, or return None."""
        for num, string in cls.choices:
            if string == the_string:
                return num
        return None
```

Comment: Given a label return the choice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution, which is just hand-coded.

```
    @classmethod
    def string_to_int(cls, the_string):
        """Convert the string value to an int value, or return None."""
        for num, string in cls.choices:
            if string == the_string:
                return num
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping and then do simple dict access by key:

```py
label_mapping = {label: value for value, label in AType.choices}
# outputs: { 'Zero': 0, 'One': 1, 'Two': 2 }

@classmethod
def string_to_int(cls, the_string):
    """Convert the string value to an int value, or return None."""
    return label_mapping.get(the_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access to the info the choice doing this:

```
AType(0).name
AType(0).label
```